# Getting error when saving Trigger

Tags: trigger

I'm new to salesforce. I'm trying to make the changes in developer console. 
We have a requirement to add PDF from external source to Sales Force Community.

```
trigger WriteAttachmentIDToEmissionTest on Attachment__c (after insert) {
    List EmissionTestList = new List();
    Set etIds = new Set();

    //make a map of ET ids to attachment ids
    Map<Id,Id> ETtoAttachmentIdMap = new Map<Id,Id>();

    for(Attachment__C att : trigger.New){
        //Check if added attachment is related to An Emission Test or not
        if(att.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Emission_Test__c.SobjectType){
            etIds.add(att.id);
            ETtoAttachmentIdMap.put(att.ParentId,att.id);
        }
    }

    EmissionTestList = [
        select Asset__c,Test_Date__c 
        from Emission_Test__c 
        where id in : etIds
    ];

    if( EmissionTestList!=null && EmissionTestList.size()>0){
        for(Emission_Test__c et : EmissionTestList) {
            et.PDFId = ETtoAttachmentIdMap.get(et.Id);
        }

        if(EmissionTestList!=null && EmissionTestList.size()>0){
            update EmissionTestList;
        }
    }
}
```

Actual Controller code, column Attachment__c we want to write a trigger to enable it to accept attachment from external source:

```
({
    doInit : function(comp, event, helper) {
        console.log('in init');
        //save filter - start
        var filterNames=new Array();
        var filterCriteria=new Array();
        var action1 = comp.get("c.getFilters");
        action1.setCallback(this, function(a) { 
            for (i = 0; i < a.getReturnValue().length; i++){
                filterNames.push(a.getReturnValue()[i].Name);
                filterCriteria.push(a.getReturnValue()[i].Filter_Criteria__c);     
            }
            console.log(filterNames);
            console.log(filterCriteria);
        });        
        $A.enqueueAction(action1);
        document.getElementById("saveFilterDialogEmission").style.visibility = "visible";
        $('#saveFilterDialogEmission').dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });        
        //save filter - end
        var action = comp.get("c.getEmissionRecords");
        action.setParams({"engType": '',
                          "oemHP": '',
                          "sidx": '',
                          "sord": '',
                          "assetId" : comp.get("v.recordId")
                         });

        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {        
            $("#jqGridEmission").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: a.getReturnValue(),
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'Id', name: 'Id', key: true, width: 150,hidden: true},
                    { label: 'Asset', name: 'Asset__c', width: 150,hidden: true},
                    { label:'Lease Name', name: 'Lease_Name__c', width: 200},
                    { label:'Engine S/N', name: 'Engine_Serial_Number__c', width: 150, classes:'colLink' },
                    { label: 'Test Date', name: 'Test_Date__c', width: 150, classes:'colLink' },
                    { label:'Type', name: 'Type__c', width: 150 },                    
                    { label:'Test Result', name: 'Test_Result__c', width: 150 },
                    { label:'Test Status', name: 'Test_Status__c', width: 150 },
                    { label:'NOX Level', name: 'NOX_Level__c', width: 150 },
                    { label:'NOX Unit', name: 'NOX_Unit__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'CO Level', name: 'CO_Level__c', width: 150 },
                    { label:'CO Unit O2 Level(%)', name: 'O2_Level_Percent__c', width: 150 },
                    { label:'VOC Level', name: 'VOC_Level__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'VOC Unit', name: 'VOC_Unit__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'Formaldehyde Level', name: 'Formaldehyde_Level__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'Formaldehyde Unit', name: 'Formaldehyde_Unit__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'Unit #', name: 'Unit_Number__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'Make', name: 'Make__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'Model', name: 'Engine_Model__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'Engine Type', name: 'Engine_Type__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'Mfr Date', name: 'Eng_Mfr_Date__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'Max OEM HP#', name: 'Max_OEM_HP__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'Max Eng Speed', name: 'Max_Engine_Speed__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'Rule Applicability', name: 'Rule_Applicability__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'NESHAP ZZZZ Designation', name: 'NESHAP_ZZZZ_Designation__c', width: 200},
                    { label:'Regulatory Justification', name: 'Regulatory_Justification__c', width: 180},
                    { label:'Company', name: 'Company__c', width: 300},
                    { label:'County', name: 'County__c', width: 150},
                    { label:'State', name: 'State__c', width: 150}, 
                    { label:'Attachment', name: 'Attachment__c', width: 150}                    

                                    ],
                width: 1040,
                height: 520,
                loadtext: 'Loading...',
                pager: '#jqGridEmissionPager',
                emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",
                sortorder: "desc",
                soratble: true,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 50],
                altRows: true,
                editurl: 'clientArray',
                loadonce: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                /*ondblClickRow: function(rowId) {
                    var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(rowId); 
                    var srId = rowData['Id'];
                    window.location.href =$A.get("$Label.c.Community_Link") + srId;
                },*/
                onCellSelect: function(rowId,iCol,cellcontent,e){
                    var cm = $("#jqGridEmission").jqGrid("getGridParam","colModel");
                    var colName = cm[iCol].name;
                    if(colName == 'Engine_Serial_Number__c'){                    
                        var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(rowId); 
                        var asstId = rowData['Asset__c'];      
                        window.location.href =$A.get("$Label.c.Community_Link") + asstId;
                    }else if(colName == 'Test_Date__c'){
                        var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(rowId); 
                        var srId = rowData['Id'];
                        window.location.href =$A.get("$Label.c.Community_Link") + srId;
                    }
                }
            }).navGrid('#jqGridEmissionPager', { 
                search: true, // show search button on the toolbar
                add: false,
                edit: false,
                del: false,
                refresh: false, view: false, position: "left", cloneToTop: false 
            },
                       {}, // edit options
                       {}, // add options
                       {}, // delete options
                       { multipleSearch: true,
                        multipleGroup: true,
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        closeAfterSearch: true, 
                        tmplLabel: 'Filters',
                        // set the names of the template
                        tmplNames: filterNames,
                        // set the template contents
                        tmplFilters: filterCriteria } // search options - define multiple search
                      )
            .navButtonAdd('#jqGridEmissionPager',{
                caption:"Export", 
                buttonicon:"ui-icon-newwin", 
                onClickButton: function(){ 
                    $("#jqGridEmission").exportToExcel({
                        includeLabels : true,
                        includeGroupHeader : true,
                        includeFooter: true,
                        fileName : "EmissionTest.xlsx",
                        //maxlength : 40 // maxlength for visible string data 
                    });   
                }, 
                position:"last"
            })
            .navButtonAdd('#jqGridEmissionPager',{
                caption:"Save Filter", 
                buttonicon:"ui-icon-newwin", 
                onClickButton: function(){ 
                    //var filters =new Array();
                    //var currentname = 'test1';
                    // get the filter
                    var filterdata = $("#jqGridEmission").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData').filters;
                    if(filterdata == null){     
                        alert('No search filters defined');
                    }else{
                        $('#saveFilterDialogEmission').dialog('open');                          
                    }
                }, 
                position:"last"
            });

            $("#jqGridEmission").trigger('reloadGrid');
            $(window).bind('resize', function() {
                var width = $('#jqGridEmission_container').width();
                $('#jqGridEmission').setGridWidth(width);
            });

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    saveFilterForm : function(comp,event,helper){
        var filtername = comp.get("v.filterName");
        if(filtername == null || filtername == ''){
            alert('Please enter Filter Name');
        }else{
            console.log(filtername);
            console.log('Current filter is saved!'+$("#jqGridEmission").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData').filters);
            helper.saveFilter(comp,filtername,$("#jqGridEmission").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData').filters);
            $('#saveFilterDialogEmission').dialog('close');
            //window.location.href='';
        }
    },

    closeFilterForm : function(comp,event,helper){
        $('#saveFilterDialogEmission').dialog('close');
    },

})
```

Comment: Are you writing code on developer console?

Comment: You need to provide code that you are trying to save. And also seems you are trying to save a Lightning Component and not a Trigger.

Comment: Amaresh, can you also include the exact error? the error you had posted earlier does not apply to the code you have posted now.

Comment: Attachment__c  is a custom object or standard? As I can see you are using ParentId which is for standard object, but adding __c means its custom. Can you specify?

Comment: Amaresh, I have updated my answer with a cleaned up version of your code and got rid of all the errors I could find, please re-view my answer once more.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question since it seems soluble at this point, but we really need to see the actual error occurring.

Comment: On a quick reading, I don't see what this new Lightning controller code has to do with the trigger. We really need a detailed, specific description of *one* problem that we can address. At this point, adding more code will not help, but more words will.

Comment: Your controller has a comma at the very end of the last method that should be removed.

Answer (score 4):

### Update 3

```
closeFilterForm : function(comp,event,helper){
    $('#saveFilterDialogEmission').dialog('close');
}, <--- Remove this comma
```

### Update 2

I've updated your code, see my notes below.

```
trigger WriteAttachmentIDToEmissionTest on Attachment (after insert) {
    //make a map of ET ids to attachment ids
    Map<Id,Id> ETtoAttachmentIdMap = new Map<Id,Id>();

    for(Attachment att : trigger.New) {
        //Check if added attachment is related to An Emission Test or not
        if(att.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Emission_Test__c.SobjectType){
            ETtoAttachmentIdMap.put(att.ParentId, att.id);
        }
    }

    List<Emission_Test__c> EmissionTestList = [
        select Asset__c, Test_Date__c, PDFId__c 
        from Emission_Test__c 
        where id in :ETtoAttachmentIdMap.keySet()
    ];

    if(!EmissionTestList.IsEmpty()){
        for(Emission_Test__c et : EmissionTestList) {
            et.PDFId__c = ETtoAttachmentIdMap.get(et.Id);
        }

        update EmissionTestList;
    }
}
```

1. Removed __c from attachment
2. Got rid of unnecessary set (etIds)
3. added __c to PDFId Field
4. You were using attachment ids in your query, I changed this to use the parent ids to properly pull in emission test records (the map's keyset). **This is probably the most impactful change.**
5. Used `list.isEmpty()` instead of `list != null && list.size() > 0`
6. Got rid of duplicate if statement

### Update

**Disclaimer:** The question has been changed fairly drastically since this answer was posted. I will update the answer with more info when OP provides an accurate description of the issue.

The original Error:

> Failed to save EmissionTestsGridComponentController.js:
>   c.EmissionTestsGridComponent:
>   org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException:
>   Expected ':'

---

Your title doesn't match your error as triggers are not in JS (I updated your title). You should also include a code sample so we can see where the issue is. Your error implies you're working in a lightning component Controller. My best guess based on your error is that you are missing a `:`

The format of a controller is:

```
{
    //                V This guy
    handleChangeEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        // Some code
    },
    handleinit : function() {
        // Some more code
    }
}
```

Notice the `:` between the function name and the definition? Chances are you are missing one of those.

Comment: Can you vote to reopen?